# Threading issue in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I create vb.net application and i add one windows form,called frmScan.
i put two textboxes and two labels. Then i write the following
thread with delegate event.

```
Private Delegate Sub DoInitializedDelegate() 

Public motdet As New Thread(AddressOf MotionDetection)

Private Sub MotionDetection()
'Do motion detection Work
'It is never ending Loop until form unload.
End Sub
```

Then I start it in my form load event.

```
Private Sub frmScan_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
motdet.Start()      
End Sub
```

So my problem started when i load the form.
i can see the form but it is like loading something.
i thought my motion detecting thread is never ending loop until form unload.
i cannot type anything inside two text box i mentions in above.
how should i do ?

Comment: Have you thought of trying a BackgroundWorker instead of a thread?  I've found in the past that they integrate a little more easily into the form model.

Comment: Are you calling `Invoke` continuously in this loop? Don't.

Comment: if its an infinite loop dont expect your UI to remain responsive. decrease the thread ThreadPriority and use a background worker as @Adrian suggested, they are of so much value.

Comment: This thread should not affect the UI responsiveness. Can you post the code in the function MotionDetection(). Moreover, if you want the lifetime of your thread to be same as the form's you can set the IsBackground property of the thread to True.

Comment: Try putting `Public motdet As New Thread(AddressOf MotionDetection) ` in your form_load event and set `.IsBackground` to true before the `.Start()`.

Comment: according to this link http://www.dotnetutorial.com/display-code.aspx?id=4, i can manage to get it. but i still don't know why delegate cannot work.

Comment: @DartfrogImi: It can, but I think you're probably just calling `Invoke` continuously, which moves back to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.DoEvents()` before calling your long running thread.

Refer example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446540.aspx

Comment: This won't do anything. (Sorry if that's not an explanation, but it's like trying to explain why `Dim x = 5 + 5` somewhere won't fix it.)